# NumberFormatException while generating the Jenkins surefire report during running Selenium tests with Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, surefire

We want to publish the Selenium test cases to the Jenkins. We configured surefire report plugin to generate HTML as following...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/htmlreport</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But we are getting the NumberFormatException while generating the report. please look into the following log.

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
Publishing Selenium report...
Copying the reports.
parsing resultFile surefire-report.html
Unable to parse surefire-report.html: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please provide the suggestions to rectify the issue.

Comment: Is there is a reason why you are not using JUNIT results generated by selenium - java?

Comment: As per the client requirement, we need to show the JUNIT results in  HTML format.

Comment: Selenium HTML report is better through executing Jenkins invoking Ant. I faced the same problem using Java. Part of Console Output of Jenkins was as below:


Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Publishing Selenium report...
Copying the reports. 
parsing resultFile test-output\html\index.html
Unable to parse test-output\html\index.html: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
Finished: FAILURE